# Symfony isValid() always returns true

Tags: php, symfony

As it stands isValid() returns true on form submission regardless of whether the fields have been filled out or not. The objective is to get isValid() method to actually check the data. Any help would be much appreciated.

Form Entity:

```
namespace Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Entity;

class Form {

    protected $email;

    protected   $id,
                $type,
                $voucher,
                $subscription,
                $affiliate;

    public function getEmail(){
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email){
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    // The rest of the getters & setters have been omitted for ease of reading, but they look very similar to the above. 
}
```

services.yml:

```
services:

    form.builder:
        class: Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder
        arguments: ['SignUpForm', 'Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Entity\Form', @event_dispatcher, @form.factory]

    premium.form.entity:
        class: Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Entity\Form
        arguments: [ ]

    premium.form.sign_up:
        class: Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Form\SignUpFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: SignUpForm }

    premium.controller.signup:
        class: Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Controller\SignUpController
        arguments: [@templating, @form.builder, @premium.form.sign_up, @form.factory, @premium.form.entity ]
```

validation.yml:

```
Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Entity\Form:
    properties:
        email:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - NotNull: ~
```

SignUpController.php:

```
namespace Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Controller;

use Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Entity\Form;
use Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Form\SignUpFormType;
use Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Form\SignUpDetailsForm;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory;


class SignUpController implements DetectionController
{
    private $_templating;
    private $_formBuilder;
    private $_form;
    private $_formFactory;
    private $_formData;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating, FormBuilder $formBuilder, SignUpFormType $signUpFormType, FormFactory $formFactory, Form $formData)
    {
        $this->_templating = $templating;
        $this->_formBuilder = $formBuilder;
        $this->_form = $signUpFormType;
        $this->_formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->_formData = $formData;
    }



    public function signUpDetailsAction()
    {
        return $this->renderForm('SignUpDetailsForm', new SignUpDetailsForm(), 'details');
    }

    public function signUpAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm($this->_form, $this->_formData);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){

            if($form->isValid()){
                dump('Form Is Valid!');
            }

            return $this->renderForm($form->createView(), 'signup');
        }

        return $this->renderForm($form->createView(), 'signup');
    }

    public function renderForm($form, $type)
    {
        return $this->_templating->renderResponse( 'PremiumBundle:Connect:'.$type.'.html.twig', array('form'=>$form));
    }

    public function createForm($type, $data = null, array $options = array())
    {
        return $this->_formFactory->create($type, $data, $options);
    }

}
```

SignUpFormType:

```
namespace Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SignUpFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', 'text', array('label'=>' ',
                                          'attr' => array('placeholder'=>'Your email', 'class'=>'email')))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(  'label'=>'Access Premium',
                                            'attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btnProceed'),
                                            'validation_groups' => true))
            ->add('facebook', 'submit', array( 'validation_groups' => false,
                                               'attr' =>array('class'=>'btn btnFacebook cancel')))
            ->add('linkedin', 'submit', array( 'validation_groups' => false,
                                               'attr' =>array('class'=>'btn btnLinkedIn cancel')))
            ->add('id', 'hidden')
            ->add('type', 'hidden')
            ->add('voucher', 'hidden');

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'SignUpForm';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bookboon\Premium\AppBundle\Entity\Form',
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you set default_class in the form type, so that the validator knows which entity to validate the form against.

Comment: Tis set, forgot to include it, please see my edit

Comment: have you enabled validation in your yaml config?

Comment: I have  framework:
                   validation: { enable_annotations: true }

In my config.yml, is that what you meant?

Comment: You don't need to enable annotations because you're using YAML

Comment: Mmmm, that code is a throwback from when I tried with annotations.... how to enable validation in yaml config then?

Comment: validation is definitely enabled because if I try to validate a non-existent property (say _phone) for example it throws an error stating that the property doesn't exist

Comment: From the docs: **The Symfony validator is enabled by default, but you must explicitly enable annotations if you're using the annotation method**

Comment: Yup, it's definitely enabled then.... still not validating though

Comment: Ok turns out validator isn't enabled by default. In order for this sort of validation to work it needs to be enabled:

framework:
       validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }